# How to reliably assess uninstalls on iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-push-notifications, uninstallation

I'm trying to detect uninstalls of our iOS app. 
I read [this document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/APNsProviderAPI.html) which gives some useful information. However, how can I understand from the error codes returned whether the user uninstalled versus disabled push notifications/has no connectivity?

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll want to use the `Feedback Service`. When a user deletes an app, the service provider should ideally stop sending notifications to that device. But Apple does not notify the service that "this device is not using your app, dont send notifications". Technically, a device which has uninstalled your app will not make it onto this list until the next time a push notification goes to the device. So you need to poll for this info using the `Feedback Service`.

Periodically, you will need to hit Apple Notification servers asking it to give you IDs that have deleted your app. Once you get them you mark them in your DB as deleted thereby not sending any more notifications. This `Feedback Service` will tell devices that have been unregistered (app uninstalled).  The part I'm not sure about is whether a user who has turned off push notifications in settings will register the same.  I believe they will not show up in the feed from the `Feedback Service`. I am certain, however, that users who are offline and the push notification is not delivered will not be included in the list.
It would be a simple test in your dev region to try the app, disable push notifications for the app, and then see if the device shows up in the feed.

Take a look at [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Appendixes/BinaryProviderAPI.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH106-SW4)

From Apple Documentation -

> Apple Push Notification Service includes a feedback service that APNs
>   continually updates with a per-application list of devices for which
>   there were failed-delivery attempts. The devices are identified by
>   device tokens encoded in binary format. Providers should periodically
>   query the feedback service to get the list of device tokens for their
>   applications, each of which is identified by its topic. Then, after
>   verifying that the application hasn’t recently been re-registered on
>   the identified devices, a provider should stop sending notifications
>   to these devices.
>
> Access to the feedback service takes place through a binary interface
>   similar to that used for sending push notifications. You access the
>   production feedback service via feedback.push.apple.com, port 2196;
>   you access the sandbox feedback service via
>   feedback.sandbox.push.apple.com, port 2196. As with the binary
>   interface for push notifications, you must use TLS (or SSL) to
>   establish a secured communications channel. The SSL certificate
>   required for these connections is the same one that is provisioned for
>   sending notifications. To establish a trusted provider identity, you
>   should present this certificate to APNs at connection time using
>   peer-to-peer authentication.

Make sure you also read up on - [Issues with Feedback Service](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2265/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010376-CH1-TNTAG34)